# Typecast on an int to address for a pointer C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand typecast on an int to address for a pointer.

The code snippet below is totally fine assigning pointer a normal format of address (&a):

```
#include <iostream>

int a;
int main() {

    int* b = &a;
    *b = 400; 
}
```

And I am trying to replicate it with typecast on an int to address for pointer and I am getting error (7906 Segmentation fault):

```
#include <iostream>

int a;
int main() {

    int* c = (int *)7;   
    *c = 300;
}
```

Does anyone know the reason or the concept why this does not work?

Thank you.

Comment: `7` is a constant literal. You are trying to interpret `7` as an address.

Comment: In the second example you make `c` point to the memory location `7`. Which isn't likely to be valid.

Comment: The concept why this doesn't work? You randomly chose a memory address (`7`) and assumed it's the address of a writable memory and also assumed that writing it would not break some other logic. Your assumption was wrong.

Comment: I saw the code somewhere else where it has "int * pt = (int *) 0xB8000000; ", and I have never seen it before, so I am just wondering how it works and in what kind of case we can use it. No matter what number I am giving, either 7 or 0xB8000000 or any other random number, it just gives errors.

Comment: The OS just does not allow you to overwrite any memory location that you want (in your case, 7 or 0x00........0111). You tried to access a location that is not part of your program's address space.

Comment: On smaller embedded systems, usually without an operating system, it's common to access addresses directly. Or if you're writing the actual operating system itself. For example the address `0xB8000` on a PC-like system is commonly the memory for the initial text-display used for printing messages at boot, so boot-loaders and early-stage operating systems tend to write to that part using a pointer to that address. Doesn't mean it's possible in a user-space application though.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I got it now. Normally we do not write like this for normal use in OS.

Comment: You could have written `int a = 7` in your first snippet. And it would be legal, initializing a memory 'cell' with 7 and overwriting it by dereferencing the pointer. You can print out addresses with `std::out << b << std::endl`. Local variables are on the stack, variables allocated with `new` in the free storage memory region.

Comment: @Sebastian Thanks for the comment. I guess the memory has been preserved when the compiler sees ```int a;```, and I tried printing out the value of ```a``` before I assigned any value to it and it shows ```a = 0```, so I guess it somehow has been initialized to ```0``` when the compiler assigns a memory to it.